# unique_together = (("name", "added_by"),) in Django model gives IntergretyError at/admin instead of Validation Error

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I want to show a validation message like "This Project already exists" in my django admin whenever i create a project with same name.

I keep getting an IntegrityError at my Name. Isn't Django supposed to validate this and give an ValidationError if I use unique_together=((,)) in my model? Or do I have to Try and Catch the IntegrityError myself?

Also i have made two users and gave permissions to them from main admin user. so i want that one user1 cannot have projects with same name like proj1  while the user2 can have name of project as proj1.
Can anyone tell me a best practice for validating unique users inside a form/model.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "added_by"),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Why dont you try `UniqueConstraint` mentioned here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint

Comment: okay will try and tell.

Comment: since `unique_together` will be deprecated